# Function firing additional time for each time it is called - jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Scope**

We have a function. Inside of it is an ajax request:

```
function search(){
 $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
        var filter = $(result).find('#myDiv');
        // populate a hidden div with this information
        $("#ladderInformation").html(filter);
    }
 });
}
```

Once this is complete, we iterate over the results of the initial ajax request, and run a new ajax request for each of them:

```
// yes, this is attached to the above, it's not outside of the first ajax call

.done(function(){
    // for every team, we're going to run this ajax call
    $('.team').each(function(i){
        $.ajax({
            url: "(we make use of $(this).text() here)",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(teamdata){
                $('#teamListing').append($(teamdata).find('#team-sheet'));    
                // for every time it runs, we'll append a div to the wrapper. 
                $('.wrapper').append('<div class="teamInfo" id="'+ Team [i] + '"></div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is all working completely fine.

Next, I manipulate the elements received:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    //this function is irrelevant to the issue
    configureTeams();
});
```

All of the above is wrapped in the first mentioned function, `search();`. We call this with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    search();
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        search();
    });
});
```

On first page load it does everything as expected.

**The Issue**

When the select listener is fired multiple times, for every time it is used, the app drastically slows down. This was also noticed when I tried to add an "auto refresh" to the results (doing so by adding `setTimeout(function(){ search() }, 5000);` to the end of the `$(document).ajaxStop(){}` function).

For every time that `search()` is called, it will fire an additional time. So, for example, if you've changed select 6 times (or left the app running and auto refreshing for 6 times), it is firing 6 times to match this, and inevitably breaks.

**Attempts to Fix**

If I were to `console.log()` in the `$(document).ajaxStop()` function, it will fire an extra time for each time `search()` has been called. This can be combated by changing it to `$(document).one('ajaxStop', function(){})` but that isn't solving the entire problem, since all that does is prevent the configuring from firing multiple times.

I have got the divs that hold the information emptying at the start of `search()`, so there are no conflicts with the same data or anything like that, I have tried managing the ajax requests in a queue, I have tried multiple methods of detecting that all of the ajax requests are finished before continuing, I have tried limiting the `$.each()` function so it doesn't exceed the required amount of iterations, but to no avail.

**TL;DR**

What I'm trying to accomplish, is that when I run a function multiple times, we completely start over each time. It seems as though it is recording each time it has been called. Could there be a solution with clearing memory, or the AJAX queue, or something like that?

I can provide the full code if that will be more helpful.

Thanks

Comment: not sure if i read it correctly, so for each time select change, you will fire ajax call to server and return to client site, and continue to fire a loop ajax again for `.team`, so if there is 10 .team, you will fire 10 time of ajax call and append it to `#teamListing` and $('.wrapper'), not sure if `.team` will dynamic increase also? if yes, it will getting slower as the `.team` is keep on increasing and the loop will keep on repeat start from 0

Comment: To simplify this, we run 1 ajax call to get a list of `<li>`'s, then, with each `<li>`, we run an ajax call and use the value of each `<li>` as part of the url, and then return our results. These results are stored in a div, which are emptied at the start of the function, so that every time we run it, we're clearing out the previous results.